# Facebook only gets my metatags if I hard-code them.It doesn't read them if I pass variables from smarty

Tags: facebook, smarty, prestashop

I am working on an online store.
It's made with Prestashop 1.3.6
I am trying to embed a like and send button in the product page.
I have set up my og tags,and tested it with the debugger.
My problem is that the tags only get read by facebook if I hardcode them in the header.tpl.

If I pass smarty variables the tags appear as empty.
It's kind of driving me crazy because I can not find someone with the same problem.

The tags appear in the browser source code in both cases (hard-coded and variable).
But facebook reads them only when I hardcode them.

Here is the link to my site,maybe you can figure it out.
The thing that I don't understand is that before putting og:tags,facebook was taking the default title and description tags off my page.
And those tags were passed by variable.
So I really don't understand why it doesn't work.
Any ideas ?

Thanx a lot in advance!

Comment: Please add the name and content of your template file in your question.